# Bind JDBI parameter inside double quotes

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, dropwizard, jsonpath, jdbi

I have a Dropwizard + Jdbi + Postgres 12 setup. I want to run following query with a SQL/Json Path Expression on a complex/nested JsonB column:

```
try (Handle handle = jdbi.open()) {
        return handle.createQuery(
                        "select data from company where" +
                                " data @?? '$.employees[*].assets.vehicle[*] ? (@.vehicleNumber like_regex \":regex\")'"
                )
                .bind("regex", somRegex)
                .map(mapper)
                .collect(toList());
    }
```

The problem is that I am unable to bind the regEx paramenter inside double quotes inside Json Path Expression, and the query returns no result. The same query works when I run it directly in Postgres or hardcode the regex in the prepared query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by using concat() to bind the param and then type cast it to jsonpath:

```
try (Handle handle = jdbi.open()) {
    return handle.createQuery(
                    "select data from company where" +
                            " data @?? CAST(concat('$.employees[*].assets.vehicle[*] ? (@.vehicleNumber like_regex \"',':regex','\")') AS jsonpath)"
            )
            .bind("regex", somRegex)
            .map(mapper)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind arguments inside string literals, this limitation comes from JDBC itself. See [docs](https://jdbi.org/#_like_clauses_with_parameters).